# Stop speech recognition when user is finished speaking

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition

How is Siri is able to determine when I'm finished speaking. The reason I would like to know is that I would like to implement similar functionality with Apple's Speech Recognition API with my app. Is this doable, or is the only way to know when the user has stopped speaking is via user input?

Comment: My understanding is that you don't need to handle "when user finishes speaking". You should read the SiriKit guide here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/ResolvingandHandlingIntents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH5-SW1.   Basically SiriKit gives you an "intent" with the data gathered from the user speech and you only need to handle the intent and perform your own operations.

Comment: The question is asking about the Speech Recognition API, not SiriKit.

Comment: Any luck? I'm struggling with this myself

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a timer, i had the same problem and I could not solve it with an elegant method.

```
fileprivate var timer:Timer?
func startRecordingTimer() {
    lastString = ""
    createTimerTimer(4)
}
func stopRecordingTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}
fileprivate func whileRecordingTimer() {
    createTimerTimer(2)
}
fileprivate var lastString = ""
func createTimerTimer(_ interval:Double) {
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({[unowned self] in
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: interval, repeats: false) { (_) in
            self.timer?.invalidate()
            if(self.lastString.characters.count > 0){
                //DO SOMETHING
            }else{
                self.whileRecordingTimer()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

and in `SFSpeechRecognitionTaskDelegate`

```
public func speechRecognitionTask(_ task: SFSpeechRecognitionTask, didHypothesizeTranscription transcription: SFTranscription) {
    let result = transcription.formattedString
    lastString = result
}
```