# Swift - Speech Recognition - stop recording

Tags: swift, speech-recognition

Most speech recognition tutorials use a simple on/off button to switch between recording states. I would like to end recording as soon as the user has stopped speaking. I tried using isFinishing from SFSpeechRecognitionTask but that seems to have more to do with the state of the microphone itself and not the level of the signal being recorded.

Comment: Did you have any success with this issue?  I am trying to doing something similar.

Comment: I had some success - the function recognitionTask has a resultHandler which has a parameter called result. By checking result.isFinal I was able to stop recording. It worked most if the time, but I never got it working perfectly. That project is sitting on a shelf for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to track the elpsed time since last result and after a certain amount of time stop recognition. result.isFinal seems not to work as it should. 
[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421159/stop-speech-recognition-when-user-is-finished-speaking) for snippet code